Why does my javascript confirm dialogue moves to the next condition even when I click cancel button?
In my button_click event, I have some "if" conditions with JavaScript confirm dialogue ("Do you want to continue?"). I expect it to stop when I press Cancel and Continue to second condition when I press 'Ok' to contine.
protected void btSendToTheRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
    if(txAmount.Text=="")
    {
        Response.Write(" <script>confirm('No Amount selected. Do you want to continue?'); </script>");
    }

    if (txDeaneries.SelectedIndex == 0)
     {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Please select current deanery.');</script>");
        return;
     }
}


Above is what I tried.
When I click Cancel button on the first condition it does not stop, instead it continues to the next condition.
I tried to put return on the first condition but the program stops both when I Click 'Ok' to continue.
It is expected to continue to the second condition only when I click 'Ok to continue' and stop when I click 'Cancel'.

Why do you expect the program to return? There is no return statement as in your second condition.

The first condition has confirm script with "Ok" and "Cancel" options. I expect the program to continue to the second condition if I press Ok and return if I press Cancel.  When I put return on the first  condition the program returns both when I Click Ok and also when I click Cancel.

You're just writing an inline script to the response. By the time it even shows in the browser, all the server-side code has already finished executing. How would you even expect this to work at all when you don't even use the return value of confirm? Think about what happens in the client, what happens on the server, and when . You probably want the client-side confirm script to happen before the request even launches and not submit it if confirm returns false.

Can you help me with the right codes. I am a beginner in JavaScript.
